# Converting raster with attribute table to ASCII using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

I have a vegetation GNN data downloaded from here https://lemma.forestry.oregonstate.edu/data/structure-maps
It comes as a grid raster file with an attribute table, but I need to convert it to a raster file in ASCII format based of certain columns.

Is there a way to do that in ArcGIS Desktop?

I tried Delete Raster Attribute Table Tool, it runs successfully, but does nothing.

Comment: Please specify in more detail what format you want as  output (preferrably with examples).

Comment: You can download the file I'm working with from the link in my question. I need to convert that file to ASCII format based of a column in the attribute table (e.g. CANCOV). I can clip a small peace of that layer and upload it if that would be more helpful?

Comment: It sounds like you are already trying to do this in ArcGIS Desktop so I am going to remove what is effectively a second question about R. You can always ask that separately if you wish.

Comment: I think you're describing the Lookup tool (followed by Raster to ASCII), using CANCOV as the lookup field: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/lookup.htm. If that doesn't work, yes, please upload a smaller sample - the original file is almost 1GB.